# Raising Exception messages in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I simply want to surface an Exception message as a bad response in DRF.

The Exception can come from anywhere in the request. So for example, some nested function can have:

`raise Exception('Something went wrong at this particular point')`

And then in my view handler, i'd simply catch the Exception and raise it:

```
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

This raises an Exception in my application, but there is no way to parse the response to get my custom message.

I can try this:

`return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`

But that returns an Exception itself:

> Object of type Exception is not JSON serializable

So how can I simply return my Exception message as a 400?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely need to cast `e` to a string first:  try:

```
return Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The underlying Response function is trying to serialize it, and the Exception class can't be converted to JSON.  You might want to return a more complete json structure too:

```
return Response({'error_message': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you